# Reversing Byte[] - why doesn't this work?

Tags: java, byte, reverse

I have an array (?) of Bytes and I want to reverse the order of them. I'm getting a NullExceptionPointer error with the following code but I don't get why it doesn't work?

Byte[] m is the thing I want to reverse.

```
    Byte[] temp = new Byte[m.length];
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = m.length - 1; i < 0; i--) {
        temp[j] = m[i];
        j++;

    }
```

Comment: Because you've not initialized `m`?

Comment: And even if `m != null`, you should use `i >= 0` rather than `i < 0`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Sorry I wasn't clear. I don't need to initialize m because it's the input parameter. Yeah, it was i >= 0. :3

Comment: Then you're passing in `null` as the value of `m`.